# 3D reconstruction based on stereo rectified edge images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two closed curve stereo rectified edge images. Is it possible to find the disparity(along x-axis in image coordinates) between the edge images and do a 3D reconstruction since I know the camera matrix. I am using matlab for the process. And I will not be able to do a window based technique as it's a binary image since a window based technique requires texture. The question how will I compute the disparity between the edge images? The images are available in the following links. Left Edge image https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5g22f6b0vge9ct/edge_left.jpg?dl=0  Right Edge Image https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjmu3pugldzo2gw/edge_right.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason why you're not using the rectified RGB images? There is a lot more data available to calculate a disparity there than in the edge images.

Comment: @Dave Durbin: The reason why I am using the edge image is that I want to look at the precise space curve of the object in view. If I use a window based method on RGB image it will contain noise as well in fact the edge reconstructed from an RGB image will not be a true representation of the edge of the object. Well, I do have the RGB images and have done all the reconstruction with that. But now I want to reconstruct with the edge image and see the exact curve in 3D.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of images, you can easily map each edge pixel from the left image to its counterpart in the right image, and therefore calculate the disparity for those pixels as usual.

The mapping can be done in various ways, depending on how typical these images are.  For example, using DTW like approach to match curvatures.

For all other pixels in the image, you just don't have any information.

Answer (score 0):

@Photon: Thanks for the suggestion. I did what you suggested. I matched each edge pixel in the left and right image in a DTW like fashion. But there are some pixels whose y-pixel coordinate value differ by 1 or 2 pixels, albeit they are properly rectified. So I calculated the depth by averaging those differing(up to 2-pixel difference in y-axis) edge pixels using least squares method. But I ended getting this space curve (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbg2q009fjji0qd/false_edge.jpg?dl=0) when they actually should have been like this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ib06yvzf3k9dny/true_edge.jpg?dl=0) which is obtained using RGB images.I couldn't think of any other reason why it would be the case since I compared by traversing along the 408 edge pixels.

Comment: The original rectified RGB images(zoomed for convenient viewing) with the edges are here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4s10anfiwsrqgmn/edge_overlaid_left.jpg?dl=0; https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfaoh62u5jtbujy/edge_overlaid_right.jpg?dl=0 .